# SQL Server: Trigger vs Database Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

What is the difference between a trigger that we use on a table, and a database trigger that is found in the below image?

[image]

what does it do and how/when to use it?

Comment: These are DDL triggers.  The documentation does a pretty good job of explaining what they are:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx.

Comment: More information about DDL triggers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/get-information-about-ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diference is that the database trigger is for DDL commands (Create/Alter/Drop). The Object language.
The Table Trigger is for DML commands (insert/update/delete). The data language

Answer (score 0):

A database trigger can prevent the dropping/creating and/or adding a table to a database. A table trigger can run code (which can log and/or cancel an operation) when an Update/Insert/Delete is executed on a table.